# Using xcom pushed value as parameter in BigQueryToGCSOperator

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow, airflow-xcom

I need to count the number of rows in a table and use the row count in the filename of an export to GCS. The following is an excerpt from my DAG.

```
with models.DAG(
    'my_dag',
    schedule_interval = '0 6 * * 1',
    start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    catchup = False
) as dag:

    # create segment filterd views to output CSV to GCS
    def prepareSegmentTables(segment, **kwargs):
        segment_table_queries = f"""
                                    TRUNCATE TABLE dataset.some_table;
                                    
                                    INSERT INTO dataset.some_table (column1)
                                    SELECT DISTINCT column1
                                    FROM dataset.some_other_table
                                    WHERE column2 = '{ segment['id'] }';
                                """
        
        # execute query
        client.query(segment_table_queries).result()
        
        # store the row counts of each type
        kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(
            key = "ROW_COUNTS",
            value = {
                        "column1": getTableRowCount("dataset.some_table"),
                    }
        )


    def get_row_counts(segment, **kwargs):
        ROW_COUNTS = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(
                        key = "ROW_COUNTS",
                        task_ids = [ f"prepare_segment_tables" ]
                    )

    #tasks
    prepare_segment_tables = PythonOperator(
                                task_id = f"prepare_segment_tables",
                                python_callable = prepareSegmentTables,
                                op_kwargs = { "segment": segment },
                                dag = dag
                            )

    export_to_gcs = BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
                            task_id = f"gcs_lr_to_li_auid_{segment['id']}",
                            source_project_dataset_table = f"{GCP_PROJECT}.{DATASET_NAME}.some_table",
                            destination_cloud_storage_uris = f"gs://{GCS_BUCKET}/{FILENAME_PATH}{segment['name']}_"
                                                                + str( ti.xcom_pull(key = "ROW_COUNTS", task_ids = [ f"prepare_segment_tables" ])[0].column1 )
                                                                + f"_{TODAY_STR}.csv",
                            # this works though
                            # destination_cloud_storage_uris = f"gs://{GCS_BUCKET}/{FILENAME_PATH}{segment['name']}_" + str( getTableRowCount("dataset.some_table") ) + f"_{TODAY_STR}.csv",
                            compression = 'NONE', export_format = 'CSV', field_delimiter = ',', print_header = True
                        )
    
    prepare_segment_tables >> export_to_gcs
```

As can be seen, I am pushing `ROW_COUNTS` into xcom while calling `prepareSegmentTables` via a PythonOperator. When I do xcom_pull inside another PythonOperator, calling `get_row_counts`, it properly pulls the value, but when I pass the same syntax as a parameter to `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator` or `BigQueryToGCSOperator`, it throws an error.

It says `ti` or `kwargs['ti']`, depending on what I use is undefined. Some people suggest using double `{{ }}`, and even that didn't work for me.

For now, I have resorted to calling `getTableRowCount()` directly, in the parameter instead of first storing it in a variable. It works, but I use the filename downstream at least one more time, and this approach results in unnecessarily querying the table for a row count multiple times.

Any help getting xcom to work or to figure out a way to get row count in the filename efficiently is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow is a distributed system. It is important to note that your DAG code isn't executed all in the same context.

The DAG is parsed and assembled on a schedule. The Task is executed on a worker. XCOM is available inside the worker context.

As you saw - `ti` or `kwargs['ti']` would allow you to access XCOMs from inside a PythonOperator (specifically the `python_callable`) but in your `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator`, you don't have `task_instance` available, as you aren't in that context.

You can use Jinja Templating to defer fetching the XCOM until you are in the correct context with the worker (read more here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html )

You probably need something like:

```
BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
  ...
  destination_cloud_storage_uris = f"gs://{GCS_BUCKET}/{FILENAME_PATH}{segment['name']}_" + "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key = "ROW_COUNTS", task_ids=["prepare_segment_tables"])[0].column1 ) }}" + f"_{TODAY_STR}.csv",
  ...
)
```

Note that I am being careful to not mix f-strings and jinja there, as they both utilize the `{}` syntax and don't play well together.
You will also probably need to ensure that your XCOM will parse as you expect in Jinja, and may want to return your XCOM differently or parse it in advanced with a PythonOperator

See here for help with what you can do within a Jinja template: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/

Note also that this works only because "destination_cloud_storage_uris" is a templated field on this operator - and not all fields are.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs.html#BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator

Comment: btw, xcom and jinja work fine if you escape the curly braces by doubling up on them. `{{{{` becomes `{{` within an f-string.